# Set ParentId on SingleEmailMessage

Tags: singleemailmessage

I reviewed the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) for the SingleEmailMessage but haven't found how to add the parentId (i.e. case Id) to the email message, is this even possible?

I want to be able to see the email on the 'Emails' related list on the parent case.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
message.ToAddresses = new String[] {'test@gmail.com'};
message.setPlainTextBody('body test');

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > {message};
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```

Comment: How about setting the whatId? 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setWhatId

Comment: By doing so, will the email appear in the Emails related list on the parent case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually **SimpleEmailMessage** is simply an apex class and its objects are not persisted to database. It is persisted in the database in **EmailMessage** after you send that message.

In order that attach that email to a case (or any other record), get that EmailMessage via SOQL query and then attach it to the desired record.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
message.ToAddresses = new String[] {'test@gmail.com'};
message.setPlainTextBody('body test');

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List < 
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > {message};
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
if(results[0].isSuccess()) {
    // Alter query such that only desired record is fetched.
    EmailMessage msg = [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM EmailMessage WHERE ToAddress = 'test@gmail.com' LIMIT 1];
    msg.ParenId = 'aabbccddeeff123'; // Your record Id
    update msg;
}
```

If you are playing with many email messages, please bulkify the above code.

Comment: Are you sure about this? AFAIK ParentId is not updateable ;(

Answer (score 1):

use **message.setWhatId(Id)**:

```java
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
message.ToAddresses = new String[] {'test@gmail.com'};
message.setPlainTextBody('body test');
message.setWhatId(case.Id)
    
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List < 
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > {message};
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```