SingleEmailMessage Sends Email, but EmailMessage not associated With the Case
I'm using the following code to create a list of Messaging.SingleEmailMessage:
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailNotifications = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for (Id caseId : cases24x7Denied){
    Case notificationCase = cases.get(caseId);
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailNotification = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    emailNotification.setWhatId(notificationCase.Id);
    emailNotification.setTargetObjectId(notificationCase.ContactId);
    emailNotification.setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(true);
    emailNotification.setTemplateId(tsEmailTemplates.get('Requested 24x7 But Not Entitled').Id);
    emailNotification.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideEmailId);
    emailNotification.setBccAddresses(getCCList(notificationCase));
    emailNotifications.add(emailNotification);
}
return emailNotifications;

The calling code calls Messaging.sendEmail with the emailNotifications list, and it seems to dependably send the email messages, but there are no EmailMessages associated with the Cases.  Oddly the EmailMessage is created and associated with the Case in my unit test.
I had the same question as TemporaryFix in this article:
What is the difference between SingleEmailMessage and EmailMessage?
I like sdfcfox's answer in that article, but the code does not associate an EmailMessage object with the Case.
The following article refutes the claim in the above article:
Outbound SingleEmailMessage doesn't attach as EmailMessage on Case
It seems to say that SingleEmailMessage...sendEmail does not result in an EmailMessage attached to a Case.
Improved questions:

Is there a way to make SingleEmailMessage.WhatId(Case.Id) associate an EmailMessage to a Case?
Alternatively, does SingleEmailMessage...sendEmail create an EmailMessage object? and Can it be definitively found in a way that can be bulkified?

I assume that "No" to these questions means that we need to create EmailMessage objects and associate them to the Cases.
Edited...
Additional Discovery:
I noted in my original description that it oddly works in the unit test.  While extending my unit testing, I noticed that the System.runAs(user) for the Case insert in the unit test is a Support Engineer.  However, in the actual org environment it will always be a portal user creating the Case from our Customer Community.  When I changed the System.runAs(user) to a portal user, it failed in the unit test too.
So the user somehow seems to affect what the system can do.  There is probably a logical explanation for this, but we generally expect trigger activity to be handled by the system not the user (even though sometimes the actions are attributed to the user).
From a SW design perspective, we expect to allow the (portal customer) user to create a case and interact with it.  We do not expect to give the customer rights to do things that the system should handle.  For example, we should not give the user rights to send email notifications.  The system should send notifications and document them with a EmailMessage attached to the Case.
Maybe we have something incorrectly configured that makes the system dependent on the user?

does this help? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/245563/12408

hm looking at old code, I've always had to create the EmailMessage myself.

Thanks Novarg, Unless I'm missing the point of that article, it doesn't resolve the question because I'm setting the WhatId.

Girbot, I'm starting to think that's the answer, but it appears that SingleEmailMessage...sendEmail at one time created the EmailMessage object and associated with the Case.  I discovered that I can use setSaveAsActivity(true) to get an Activity (Task) object associated with the Case, but still no EmailMessage.

There is a comment in my code about setSaveAsActivity not being bulkfied, not in a position to confirm/test but watch out for that. Do you have enhanced email on? I do not.

We have Enhanced Email enabled.  I'm not interested in setSaveAsActivity other than to resolve the issue, but it didn't.  I'm just feeling around in the darkness created by the absence of documentation and two conflicting articles.  I don't mind to create an EmailMessage object.  I just want to know that's the best way to go.

I noted in my original description that it oddly works in the unit test. While extending my unit testing, I noticed that the System.runAs(user) for the Case insert in the unit test is a Support Engineer. However, in the actual org environment it will always be a portal user creating the Case from our Customer Community. When I changed the System.runAs(user) to a portal user, it failed in the unit test too.
So the user somehow seems to affect what the system can do.
